# Stricter session control methods

Tags: php, session

In a Nutshell: this is a question, about improving the security of sessions in-order to prevent them from session fixation/hijacking

I have a user registration form, login and article posting form. 
Now, when user registers, logs in or posts somethings there is always thank you page different for all three. More specifically 'thankyou.php'

The problem is users can access the static thank you page, by typing the url 'site.com/thanks.php'

I don't want this to happen, I want those page to show up only when a specific tasks have been arbitrated.

So, I thought about about making sql query's to see if users has posts for the last 5 seconds and show thank you page, or show 404 but, It's seems unnecessary to create a query just for than one. And, Since I think PHP is flexible if you guys give me an idea I could probable learn something new on the way, on how to achieve this.

Comment: When you process your form post for any action, set a flag in `$_SESSION` that it has occurred. On the thankyou.php, check if the session flag is set. If it isn't, redirect back to some other page. If it is, display the thank you message and then _unset_ the session flag.

Comment: Can you tell where you are processing the form submission? In thankyou.php?

Comment: No, there is post_article.php and after authentication, and posting to database is compete, there is re-direct page to thankyou.php page. the thankyou page has nothing except what  says, " thank you for posting this article " and takes the user to another page after 5 seconds. But, in the post_article page if I start a session, it will give me error, because a session (for logged in) must have been already opened for the user to post things in the first place.

Comment: Eritrea, I've modified the code in my answer. See if this could work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the page with the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ([enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) viewing from they are coming to thankyou.php page.

Comment: Thank you all for your fast answers, Estefano, I like your suggestion too. Can you elaborate perhaps.. How do you create the function 
That, says, 
    if(visitor is comming from post page) { print thank you }else { print 404 page }

Comment: Of course. The index HTTP_REQUEST represents the URL from you come. You can do something like this:

if( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://localhost/register.php" )
{
 exit( "Thanks you" );
}
else
{
 exit( "404 error" );
}

Answer (score 1):

You Can Achieve this by settling the session like this:

```
if($_SESSION['registration']=="registration")
{
echo "Thank you for registering";


 unset($_SESSION['registration']); 

}
elsif($_SESSION['login']=="login")
{
echo "Thank you for login";
unset($_SESSION['login']); 

}
elseif($_SESSION['post']=="post")
{
echo "Thank you for Post";
unset($_SESSION['post']); 
}
else
{
echo "session is not set,something is wrong";
}
```

So set the values in session on html page like.

```
$_SESSION['login']="login";
```

//like for others also

Comment: But whenever I try to make a new session, while a session is running already, it gives me an error. Ex: When A user is about to post something, he/she has to be logged in first, that means $_SESSION['logged_in'] is already running, so when making a post, if I try to set up a Session, it will give error saying that a session has already been started. It's says something like " A header has been sent already..."

Comment: only close the particular session

Comment: the error is coming because you are starting the session on each page,no need of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Harshal. Btw, since I am new to PHP I've never used either thought it was possible to declare multiple sessions another than the only session used to log-in/log-out user. 

I will work on your answers tonight. 

Also, I am trying to hire PHP programmers to build a file uploading script where security is the most important... Is it possible to post it in stackoverflow, or are you interested... ?

Comment: you can use, webzuru@yahoo.com